# MySql & PHP Code are showing as plain text

Tags: php, html, mysql, localhost

In cPanel I have no problem those are working fine. But in localhost I am getting so much error.

```
 Notice: Undefined variable: eroare in C:\xampp\htdocs\invo\install\index.php on line 68

Notice: Undefined variable: suc in C:\xampp\htdocs\invo\install\index.php on line 69
```

index.php files below:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if($_POST['admin_user']=='' || $_POST['admin_pass']==''){
        $eroare='Admin User/Pass Empty!';
    }
    if(!@mysql_connect($_POST['mysql_host'],$_POST['mysql_user'],$_POST['mysql_pass'])){
        $eroare='MySQL Connection Failure';
    }   

    if(!@mysql_select_db($_POST['mysql_db'])){
        $eroare='MySQL Database Not Found!';
    }
    if(!$eroare){
    $filename       = 'sql.sql';
        $templine = '';
        $lines    = @file($filename);
        if(is_array($lines)){
            foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
                if (substr($line, 0, 2) != '--' && $line != '') {
                    $templine .= $line;
                    if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';') {
                        mysql_query($templine) or print('Error performing query \'<b>' . $templine . '</b>\': ' . mysql_error() . '<br /><br />');
                        $templine = '';
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $myFile = "../inc/db.php";
            $fh = @fopen($myFile, 'w+') or $success=1;
            $stringData = '<?php
                $host      = "'.$_POST['mysql_host'].'";
                $username  = "'.$_POST['mysql_user'].'";
                $password  = "'.$_POST['mysql_pass'].'";
                $db        = "'.$_POST['mysql_db'].'";
                mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("<center><font color=\"darkred\"><b>Cannot connect to database!</b></font></center>");
                mysql_select_db($db);
            ?>';
            @fwrite($fh, $stringData);
            @fclose($fh);   
            mysql_query("insert into config(name,value) values('admin_user','".$_POST['admin_user']."')")or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_query("insert into config(name,value) values('admin_pass','".$_POST['admin_pass']."')")or die(mysql_error());

            if($success!=1){
                $_SESSION['logged']=1;
                $suc="Successfully Installed!<br/>Please configure your script from the <a href='../settings.php'>Settings Tab</a>";    

            }else
                $suc='<b>Success!</b> The inc/db.php file <b>could not be created</b>. Please rename the db_config.php to db.php and configure it manually by opening the file in a text editor through FTP!';

    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CDM Maker Installation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="install.css" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>

        <div id="container2">
            <div id="container">
                <div class='header'>Installation</div>
                <div class="content">
                    <?php if($eroare){?><div class='error'><?php echo $eroare?></div><?php }?>
                    <?php if($suc){?><div class='suc'><?php echo $suc?></div><?php }?>
                        <form action='' method='POST'>          
                            <table width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label for='username'>Admin Username</label>
                                        <input type='text' class='login' name='admin_user' id='username' value='<? echo $_POST['admin_user']?>' placeholder="admin" required/>  

                                        <label for='parola'>Admin Password</label>
                                        <input type='text' class='login' name='admin_pass' id='parola' value='<? echo $_POST['admin_pass']?>' placeholder="admin" required/>                                        

                                        <label for='host'>MySQL Host</label>
                                        <input type='text' class='login' name='mysql_host' id='host' value='<? echo $_POST['mysql_host']?>' placeholder="localhost" required/>

                                        <label for='user'>MySQL User</label>
                                        <input type='text' class='login' name='mysql_user' id='user' value='<? echo $_POST['mysql_user']?>' placeholder="johndoe" required/>

                                        <label for='pass'>MySQL Password</label>
                                        <input type='text' class='login' name='mysql_pass' id='pass' value='<? echo $_POST['mysql_pass']?>' placeholder="********" required/>

                                        <label for='db'>MySQL DB</label>
                                        <input type='text' class='login' name='mysql_db' id='db' value='<? echo $_POST['mysql_db']?>' placeholder="my_database" required/>

                                        <div style='clear:both; height:15px;'></div>
                                        <center><button class="submit" name='submit' type="submit">Install</button></center>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </form>                 
                </div>          
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried ioncube but i think something is missing in my localhost, please suggest me that what can i do to run this on my localhost. This undefine variable is declaring only in localhost but bot in cpanel.

Comment: Could you specify which lines are `68` and `69`?

Comment: i think this can be because the variables are declared inside conditions that may not be fulfilled in your localhost.

Comment: You assign the both variable as local (within if loop),so didn't use below

Answer (score 2):

Initialize **All** variable at the start of your file No matter what

```
    $eroare = $suc  = '';
```

And please use good IDE like PHPStorm and click Inspect Code tool to check weak errors and warnings.

On server , warnings, errors are turned Off . So its nightmare to see your code failing without giving any warning. So pls inspect code and then only upload on live server.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a higher level of error reporting enabled in localhost and not on the remote machine. This Notice level error shouldn't stop script execution. If you want to fix the error, use a `!empty($variable)` expression inside the if statements like this:

```
            <div class="content">
                <?php if(!empty($eroare)){?><div class='error'><?php echo $eroare?></div><?php }?>
                <?php if(!empty($suc)){?><div class='suc'><?php echo $suc?></div><?php }?>
                    <form action='' method='POST'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this script.

Add this two lines after session start() function.

```
 $eroare='';
 $suc='';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (empty($_POST['eroare'])) {
    $eroare="";
} else {
    $eroare=$_POST['eroare'];
}
```